Хеш-ссылки в Nuxt 3 запускают миддлвары
Мне нужно сделать простое содержание статьи в приложении на Nuxt 3. Содержание генерируется джаваскриптом, то есть во vue-шаблоне этой верстки нет. Само содержание в целом работает, но:

Настройка на плавный скролл работает только на компонент NuxtLink, а на обычный <a> не распространяется
При нажатии на ссылку, каждый раз тригерятся все миддлвары, и соответственно летят запросы на бэкенд, при том что страница не меняется. Это работает и с <a> и с <NuxtLink>, но для <NuxtLink> срабатывает только один раз, а для <a> - на каждое нажатие

Пример кода сгенерированной ссылки:
<a href="#examples" aria-current="page">Примеры</a>


Довольная старая проблема, вам нужна интерполяция из вашей сырой вёрстки в пригодную для накста среду, года 3 назад юзал пакет nuxt-interpolation (скорее всего устарел), но это поможет вам дать какую-то почву, возможно уже есть готовые решения, но именно пару лет приходилось юзать подобную вещь. P.S. Кстати статьи можно создавать на основе MD контента и решить ваши проблемы, это более правильное решение под ваши задачи.

@MoloF Увы, ничего не меняется :(
Там ещё появился nuxt3-interpolation, его тоже попробовал
